# Exporting just a single file

Tags: bash, shell, path

To make scripts accessible from anywhere in the terminal, one can use the following sequence of commands:

```
PATH=$PATH:some_path_here
export PATH
```

Which includes all files at the path sent in alongside all of its subfolders. Which means from then on just typing the name of a script stored within this folder structure will execute it.

How do I export only a single file this way instead of an entire folder alongside all its subdirectories?

Comment: I don't know how you can export a file.

But why don't you, for example move your script to a new directory (to have only that script in your dir) and add the directory to the path?

Comment: It would complicate matters in the folder structure that I have alongside decreasing overview of the system. Also I don't like living with limitations.

Comment: Regarding your comments about *folder structure*: Note that a files in a `PATH`'d directory are in the `PATH`, but files in subdirectories (of that directory) are not automatically included in the PATH. Each directory must be individually incluede in `PATH`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Seems `alias` is what you need.
You can specify any word to alias and set what will be execute when you execute your word.

```
alias newcommand='/path/to/your/command'
```

You can put it in you ~/.shellrc (where shell is your shell, so for `bash` it will be `~/.bashrc`) and it will be available after start.

For more information look [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/aliases.html).

Comment: The issue with this is that the alias will not be available in other processes, correct? Whereas if it'd been added to the path it would have been. For example, in ruby `system("myalias")` returns nil.

Comment: alias does not work in subshells from my testing

Answer (score 6):

Create a `symbolic link` to your file, and place it in a suitable `PATH`'d directory, eg `$HOME/bin` or whatever.

```
ln -s "/path/to/my-file"  "$HOME/bin/my-file"
```

Comment: I think this is preferable to the alias method (currently the accepted answer) as the alias will not work in a non-interactive shell (e.g. from within a Make file) whereas this solution will.

Answer (score 3):

To explain the background for Rush's answer, `export` does *not* do anything with the executables in `$PATH`. `export PATH` simply [means](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Parameters#Variable_Types) "I want the PATH variable to be inherited by all child processes." And what happens when you type `myprogram` on a prompt and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> is a series of [lookups within the shell](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/CommandsAndArguments#Types_of_Commands).

> When a command is specified in BASH without a pathname (e.g. myprogram, or ls), and it isn't an alias, function, builtin or keyword, BASH searches through the directories in PATH, in order from left to right, to see whether they contain an executable of the name you typed.

`$PATH`, in other words, is a list of *directories*, which is why it can't be used for single commands (except implicitly, by putting the executable in a separate directory). You can't promote a command to a builtin or keyword, but you *can* create a function or alias. See the previous link for a simple explanation of their differences.